# Unable to view boostrap applied to tabel [ using striped-table ]

Tags: razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

below is my cshtml view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
@model IEnumerable<Employee.Models.Family>


<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class=" table table-striped">
        <thead class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Occupation)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Age)
                </th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="table table-striped">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Occupation)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateOfBirth)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I am creating asp.net mvc application. using bundleconfig.cs file

below is the bundleconfig.cs file

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace Employee
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"
                      ));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

below is the UI where i am unable to see boostrap class stripped table applied

[image]

Created new asp.net mvc application so already have bootstrap - css content script exist in project

Let me know if more information required.

Comment: I think bootstrap is not applied on your project

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do it? or What am I missing here?

Comment: I dont know asp.net, sorry